# PERL: parsing a multiple line result

Tags: perl, parsing

I was looking for the best way to parse some text results which appear on multiple line.

The results are coming from ldapSearch and are presented in such a way:

```
sn: 1234

name: frank

mail: franl@gmail.com

phone: 123 456 7890
```

---

```
sn: 2345

name: john

mail: john@gmail.com

phone: 123 456 7890
```

---

Although this can easily be done by putting all lines in an `@array` and then using split to get the actual value, my problem is that depending on the specific record, some lines might be omitted when dont contain any value.

So some records might show up as:

```
sn: 3456

name: mary

phone: 234 567 8901 (missing mail attribute)
```

So in this case, blindly reading for the position number won't help. 
Any idea of a way to  actually search for the line name and then read the result?

Many thanks,
Frank

Comment: Have you thought about using an LDAP module from CPAN?

Comment: Are you trying to re-format the data and save to a new file? Or load the data into an array/hash in Perl?

Comment: I need to use is the script to collect specific fields from an LDAP archive. Since not all attributes are popilated I need to be able to detect which fields are valid and distinguish them based on the format (name : value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might achieve what you're after:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $infile = 'in.txt';
open my $input, '<', $infile or die "Can't open to $infile: $!";
```

Input:

```
sn: 1234
name: frank
mail: franl@gmail.com
phone: 123 456 7890
sn: 2345
name: john
mail: john@gmail.com
phone: 123 456 7890
name: bob # This entry has only a name and number
phone: 44 4232 232
```

-

```
while (<$input>){
    chomp;
    my ($sn) = /sn: (\d+)/;
    print "Sn: $sn\n" if $sn;
    my ($name) = /name: (\w+)/;
    print "Name: $name\n" if $name; 
    my ($email) = /mail: (.+\@.+)/;
    print "Email: $email\n" if $email;  
    my ($phone) = /phone: (.*)/;
    print "Phone: $phone\n" if $phone;

    # do something with the variables...

}
```

Outputs:

```
Sn: 1234
Name: frank
Email: franl@gmail.com
Phone: 123 456 7890
Sn: 2345
Name: john
Email: john@gmail.com
Phone: 123 456 7890
Name: bob
Phone: 44 4232 232
```

Comment: You guys are great, thank you. Give me some time to implement it and test it and I will get back to you. I am trying the second scrit...it is a little bit less cryptic.

Comment: @user3008283 - pleasure. Remember to select the answer that best achieves your goal as correct...

Comment: I have a problem with your implemenation (FlyingFrog). 
I query a single AD record at the time with ldapsearch and I put all the results in an @array, If I feed this array to your string it hangs (using while). 

If instead i gather the results inside a $string and feed it to your script, it only parse the last attribute of the list.
This is an example of the $string I get as output from ldapsearch

dn: CN=12345,OU=myou
cn: 12345
sn: Smith
department: mydepartment
name: frank
mail: Frank@gmail.com

Comment: It is detecting Name and Email but not the other fields.

Comment: Is it possible that the problems is the results are not exactly in the same line? the @array or $string both are made of multiple lines. perhaps I should try removing the line feeds.

Comment: The regexs I've used will work on the input data provided, but might not work if the format changes. Re-edit you question to include some examples of where it doesn't match, and I can change my answer to fix it.

Comment: Thank you FlyingFrog, I think I found the issue. It had to do with the type of value specified for each fiedl. Since they are all strings I used the /w delcaration. Now I get it for all fields exept for the sn: field which gives me 1 as a result instead of the actual string. I try to attach the results of the ldaspearch below. Consider they are in column not in straight line:

dn: CN=12345,OU=myou

cn: 12345

sn: Smith

department: mydepartment

name: frank

mail: Frank@gmail.com

Comment: That's because the regex I put for that field only captures digits. If the sn can be digits or other characters replace with `my ($sn) = /sn: (.*)/;` Also, remember to enclose your $var in brackets, otherwise it will return 1

Comment: I all, I found a problem with the script. It chops names made of two words, wuch as : John Paul. This way I get only John. Is there anyway to amend this?

Answer (score 1):

You can read all attributes into hash,

```
chomp(@array);
my %user = map { split /\s*:\s*/, $_, 2 } @array;

# print $user{name}, $user{phone}
```

Comment: thank you mpapec, this string is not enough since not all fields might be there. It depends on the AD record. Some might have more attributes than other and the script must be able to recognize them

Comment: @user3008283 can you post content of such array? Only present attributes get parsed.

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate over the lines, looking for an indication that the current entity has changed:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my %records;
my $sn = 'unknown';

while (my $line = <>) {
    chomp $line;
    next unless $line;

    my ($key,$value) = $line =~ m/^(\w+):\s*(.*)/;

    if ($key eq 'sn') {
        $sn = $value;
    }

    $records{$sn}->{$key} = $value;
}

use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper( \%records );
```